# How to ensure transformations with output to more than one output table are carried out as atomic operations in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-cde

I am totally new to ETL's in general and working on Pentaho kettle. I have made some transformations which involve writing output to more than one database tables and want to make sure that writing to these multiple tables is carried out as an atomic operation i.e. in a transaction so that in case of any errors the entire thing can be rolled out. Need help on how that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

In Spoon, go to the Transformation properties (Ctrl-T), select the "Miscellaneous" tab and tick the box next to "Make the transformation database transactional"

If you work with the raw XML, it's the `<unique_connections>N</unique_connections>` option under

```
<transformation>
  <info>
```

Comment: Thanks Noah,,damn these people...the question was actually changed to something i didn't want to ask, infact I have already done that and am facing an issue now. Getting an exception-

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@7c02dce0 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.**"